# Is there a way to print a default string if the variable you're trying to print isn't defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm querying an activity log via API that returns a dict. Each activity has 50 or more keys/properties. I only want to print the handful of properties that are relevant to me. Not every property I'm trying to print, like deviceIP, is always populated. If it's not populated, I want to print an empty string in place of the variable.

Is there an inline/simple way to print a default value? Something like:
`print(activity['deviceIP'] or "")`

Comment: Note, this isn't an issue of a *variable being defined*, but of whether or not a *key exists in a dictionary*

Comment: In particular, `activity['deviceIP']` is not a variable. `activity` is a variable, and `activity['deviceIP']` is an expression that attempts to retrieve a particular value from the mapping that `activity` refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary has a `get` method which returns a default value instead of raising an exception. What you want is:

```
print(activity.get('deviceIP', ""))
```